# Split file based on a field in Bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a quick question about creating files based on a field. I have a text file like this with ~ 17 million of lines

```
#head file
1:85928892
1:107819621
2:36082010
2:128341232
3:209652100
3:51112281
4:55643311
4:52236363
5:38213701
5:4429872
```

I would like to create different files using the first part of the line, just before the `:` part, so, my desired output would be:

```
file.1
1:85928892
1:107819621

file.2
2:36082010
2:128341232

file.3
3:209652100
3:51112281

file.4
4:55643311
4:52236363

file.5
5:38213701
5:4429872
```

The numbers before `:` go from 1 to 22, I could do it in R but i would like to do it in bash/awk since it will be likely faster

Comment: "*I want to do X*" is not a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F':' '{print > "file."$1}' input
```

give this one-liner a try, didn't test, but it should go.

Comment: I was expecting (propably wrongly) that `>>` would be used to append entries in each file. Can awk write all entries at once with one single file write using `>`?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou awk's `>` will leave the file open, unless you explicitly `close` it. Therefore, "appending" happened. But when the first time opening file with `>`, the content of the file will be cleared.

Comment: OK , thanks for the clarification. I did not know that file remains open in awk.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou it is easy to test, you make a loop, say 1- 5000 (a big number), and do `print "foo" > i` , you should get "too many open files" something like that error msg